# WsseAuthentication store nonce using Redis

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, redis, redis-cache

I cannot figure out how to use another Cache service for storing my nonces using the WsseAuthentication. The documentation is unclear to me. Can anybody help me setup my nonce cache for use with Redis?

Currently, I know how to add a new nonce cache service id, like this:

```
firewalls:
    #...
    wsse_secured:
        #...
        wsse:
            #...
            nonce_cache_service_id: cache_nonces
```

and I know how to create this service id:

```
services:
    cache_nonces:
        class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\RedisCache
        arguments: ???
```

But I don't know what arguments to give. When I use RedisCache, it expects a Redis object, and I dont know where to get this object and add this to arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove "arguments:", the class Doctrine\Common\Cache\RedisCache https://github.com/doctrine/cache/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/RedisCache.php doesn't have a constructor, so you should not pass any variables with "arguments"

Comment: doesn't work, it says can't do get() on non-object, I need to pass something. It might be that all the code I provided isn't good. I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: t says can't do get() - can you post more detailed text about the error